# Hide/Show imageView or textView in a widget in Android

Tags: android, widget, textview, imageview, hide

im going crazy day by day.

I`ve been working on a simple widget, that it has an ImageView and a TextView(with a background image) in front of that image. My wish is to make dissappear the textview and/or the imageView and reappear it/them when i wanted.

My eyes and mind hurt, i always find how to hide imageViews or textviews when working into an activity, but i dont need that. 
Widgets uses RemoteViews (not Views) so i can't use the lovely `textview.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);` 
and some other great methods.

Plz help this crazy person.
any alternatives are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See this excellent tutorial:

http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/

To hide an image in this tutorial, instead of changing it, in MyWidgetIntentReceiver class, updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener() method, use:

```
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_image, View.GONE);
```

etc. as needed.

Greg